# How to set the opacity of an image drawn to a canvas with drawImageRect?

Tags: dart, flutter, skia

I'm drawing to a [Canvas](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html) in Flutter using [drawImageRect](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawImageRect.html):

```
canvas.drawImageRect(image, sourceRect, destRect, _paint);
```

I have an Opacity value (a double between 0 and 1). How do I paint the image using this value (so that 0 is not visible and 0.5 is half-opacity)?

Answer (score 5):

Just set the color opacity

```
final _paint = Paint();
final opacity = 0.5;
_paint.color = Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, opacity);
canvas.drawImageRect(image, sourceRect, destRect, _paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process the image before rendering using [this library](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/image/latest/image/image-library.html). Also I would suggest you to do all operations of this library using the isolates, using the `compute()` function of flutter would be easy as it blocks the whole UI.